# VB.NET - CSV Import

Tags: vb.net, csv

I've a large CSV file composed by variable number of lines and columns.
Each of the columns corresponds to an Hex value that need to be converted to different formats.
The first step that I've completed is to import the CSV into an Array of Arrays.

The import is quite fast and stable however my question is, how is the best way to manage and convert the hexValues ?

The final output will be a CSV of converted values.

The code used for the CSV import is the following:

```
Private Function CSVRead(iFile As String) As String()()
    Dim RC()() As String
    Dim Lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(iFile)
    ReDim RC(Lines.Length - 1)
    For I As Integer = 0 To Lines.Length - 1
        RC(I) = Lines(I).Split(";"c)
    Next
    Return RC
End Function
```

Comment: Hello!  Can you post more context, such as a small example of what values might be inside the CSV?  Can you explain more about what you want to convert the hex values into?  Should they go from [hex to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774719/convert-hex-strings-to-integers)?  [Hex to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642417/how-do-you-convert-hex-to-decimal-using-vb-net)?

Comment: The hex data are basically strings in the format “0xFFFFFF”. These values could be converted in different format such as signed or unsigned integers some contain BCD data from some others I need to extract single bits. All the conversion info are coming from a user configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

One remark: `ReadAllLines` will not be achieve good performance on large files because it "Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array, and then closes the file." [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8).

Do you really need to do that ? Why not just iterate on the file and process it line by line ? `ReadLines` would be a better alternative [C#: File.ReadLines() vs File.ReadAllLines() — and why should I care?](https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-file-readlines-vs-file-readalllines-4742d738064e)

Rather than use outdated string arrays use `List Of(String)` instead. Thus your function could return a `List Of(String)`.

There is a lot of code samples for importing CSV files, for example:
[How to: read from comma-delimited text files in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files). So I am wondering how you came up with this solution, that may work fine enough but is another way of reinventing the wheel.

I gather that your intention is to produce another CSV file after making some conversions, so the best approach would be to simply read the source file in a loop, line by line, and write to the destination file in parallel. The process can be more direct.

Unfortunately you omitted the most salient details, because you are not saying much about those hex values, not showing how you currently convert them, and to what they should be converted. So I am not sure what you want exactly but here is an idea: converting from base 16 to 10

```
dim h as string = "FF"
Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(h, 16)
' returns 255
console.WriteLine(i)
```

> The base of the number in value, which must be 2, 8, 10, or 16.

Reference: [ToInt32(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_)

If that does not cover all your needs then you need to be more specific.

It seems that `0xFFFFFF` (from your comment) is properly handled as the function returns 16777215. But you should provide a list of all possible expected formats, and expected results, your question is still vague in terms of requirements. You need to outline all the possible cases, and all the transformations you want to be able to perform, only then it will be possible to work out a complete solution.

Comment: Sorry to not be so precise but I’m still trying to understand all the aspects of this project. 
Most of the data must be converted in signed or unsigned integers however the above string is not all data bits.
As example I've a stored value of 0x7FFFE0; in this only 15 out of 24 bits are data and in detail LSB is 6 and MSB is 20 and the value must be converted to signed int.
From some others is required to extract single bits from LSB to MSB and store them in x different columns.
Consider that a standard input file has hundreds of columns and tens of thousands lines.